# Amazon S3 copying multiple files from one bucket to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I have a large list of objects in source S3 bucket and i selectively want to copy a subset of objects in to destination bucket.
As per [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html) here it seems its possible with `TransferManager.copy(from_bucket, from_key, to_bucket, to_key)`, however i need to do it one at a time.

Is anyone aware of other ways, preferably to copy in a batched fashion instead of calling copy() for each object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to copy a whole directory, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://source-bucket/folder/* s3://destination-bucket/folder/
```

However, since you wish to selectively copy files, there's no easy way to indicate which files to copy (unless they all have the same prefix).

Frankly, when I need to copy selective files, I actually **create an Excel** file with a list of filenames. Then, I create a formula like this:

```
="aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/"&A1&" s3://destination-bucket/"
```

Then just use **Fill Down** to replicate the formula. Finally, copy the commands and paste them into a Terminal window.

If you are asking whether there is a way to **programmatically copy multiples between buckets using one API call**, then the answer is **no, this is not possible**. Each API call will only copy one object. You can, however, issue multiple copy commands in parallel to make things go faster.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a programmatic way. Wanting to confirm if sdk support them before implementing parallelism myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible via the S3 console but using the SDK there's no such option. Although this isn't the solution to your problem, this script selectively copies objects one at a time and if you're reading from an external file, it's just a matter of entering your file names there.

```java
ArrayList<String> filesToBeCopied = new ArrayList<String>();
filesToBeCopied.add("sample.svg");
filesToBeCopied.add("sample.png");
String from_bucket_name = "bucket1";
String to_bucket = "bucket2";
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("<key>","<secret>");
final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).build();
ListObjectsV2Result result = s3.listObjectsV2(from_bucket_name);
List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = result.getObjectSummaries();
try {
    for (S3ObjectSummary os : objects) {
        String bucketKey = os.getKey();
        if (filesToBeCopied.contains(bucketKey)) {
             s3.copyObject(from_bucket_name, bucketKey, to_bucket, bucketKey);
        }
    }
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
```